# Getting error: "It is not possible to mix sequential repair and incremental repairs" when trying to do incremental repair

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to do incremental repair on my nodes and I'm following this guide [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesMigration.html#opsRepairNodesMigration__mark-all-tables-repaired)

After that I executed the command **./bin/nodetool repair --inc** and it gives me the following error:

```
[2019-01-17 21:10:38,827] Nothing to repair for keyspace 'dse_perf'
[2019-01-17 21:10:38,835] Nothing to repair for keyspace 'system'
[2019-01-17 21:10:38,863] Starting repair command #5, repairing 768 
ranges for keyspace dse_system (parallelism=SEQUENTIAL, full=false)
[2019-01-17 21:10:38,867] It is not possible to mix sequential repair 
and incremental repairs.
[2019-01-17 21:10:38,877] Starting repair command #6, repairing 512 
ranges for keyspace my_keyspace (parallelism=SEQUENTIAL, full=false)
[2019-01-17 21:10:38,880] It is not possible to mix sequential repair 
and incremental repairs.
[2019-01-17 21:10:38,893] Starting repair command #7, repairing 512 
ranges for keyspace system_traces (parallelism=SEQUENTIAL, full=false)
[2019-01-17 21:10:38,895] It is not possible to mix sequential repair 
and incremental repairs.
```

I don't understand what it actually means. I tried searching online but those it tells something about system limitation like [here](https://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/156tvnnw4x/mixing-incremental-repair-with-sequential)

But I'm not totally convinced what it's trying to say.

I'm doing this on Ubuntu 16.04. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what version of DSE you're using?

Comment: DSE version 5.0.15

Answer (score 0):

The guide that you're using is for very old version of Cassandra.

Incremental repair has some problems in implementation, so it was switched off as default in DSE 5.1.3. Depending on the version of the DSE you may need better to:

- use OpsCenter's repair service to schedule the repairs most effective way. If you don't want use OpsCenter, just use standard (non-incremental) repairs;
- in DSE 6.0+ you can enable [NodeSync](https://www.datastax.com/2018/04/dse-nodesync-operational-simplicity-at-its-best) on tables, that will perform repairs in the background (this could be also done via OpsCenter).